# ¿Cómo impido retroceder después de logear un usuario?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un login, y lo quiero es saber cómo impido retroceder en el explorador después de ingresar mi usuario y contraseña en el login.

Me refiero a que cuando un usuario entre al sistema, y luego decida retroceder con el botón de retroceder del explorador, este no me dirija a la pagina del login si no que me mantenga dentro del sistema web.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
            }else{
                echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
                }
    }else{
?>
<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>
<p>This is secure area.</p>
<p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></p>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('login');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para impedir que el usuario 'logineado' retroceda a la página anterior, antes de enviarle, debes de comprobar que la sesión asociada con el usuario en cuestión exista (se mantenga) o no, si se mantiene se le realiza una redirección con la función *header(string)* a tu página **index.php**, sino, dónde tu desees.

> Ejemplo de uso

```
$key = 'usuario';
if (isset($_SESSION) && is_array($_SESSION) && array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION)) {
    header('location:index.php');
    exit();
} else {
    header('location:login.php');
    exit();
}
```

> mysql está obsoleto, utilizar mysqli o PDO.

Cómo punto importante, ya no es recomendable realizar la conexión a base de datos (en tu caso mysql) con las funciones que engloban '**mysql**', ya qué ahora está obsoleta ([ENLACE](http://php.net/manual/es/migration55.deprecated.php)), lo recomendado ahora es utilizar '[**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)' (solo MySQL) o '[**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)' (acepta hasta 12 bases de datos).

Cómo añadido, aquí unas clases de PDO, Session y Cookie para un uso muy simple: [ENLACE](https://github.com/ticdenis/NOTES_Ticdenis/tree/master/PHP).

Answer (score 2):

No puedes impedir que el usuario retroceda y vaya a la página anterior. Sin embargo, lo que puedes hacer es detectar si el usuario está logueado, y en ese caso llevarle a su página mediante una redirección por header.

De esta forma, cuando el usuario se conecte y le de al botón de volver, acabará en su página de nuevo.